# "follow suit" or "follow the suit" (when the idea is following someone's example)?

Tags: phrase-usage

Should it be "follow suit" or "follow the suit" when the idea being expressed is following some example?

For example,

> As his passive vocabulary was gradually increasing and, as his
> classmates were showing more and more of a desire to participate in
> conversations and other in-class activities, he **also followed the
> suit**.

I've heard both expressions, so I am confused now.

Comment: I can't imagine where you've "heard both expressions". I've ***never, ever*** heard anyone introduce a definite article into idiomatic ***to follow suit** (= **do likewise**)*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the "validity" of a non-existent usage

Comment: "Follow the suit" ... "That posh gentleman knows the way." [Lexico **1.3**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/suit)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - "I can't imagine where you've "heard both expressions"" - Just imagine any non-English speaking country where they go all out to make English their second language (Singapore, Hong-Kong, Taiwan, the Philippines, etc. ). That's where you could easily hear all these things and get easily affected by when you yourself are not a native English speaker either.

Comment: @brilliant: I assume it's reasonably obvious to people living in those countries whether someone they hear speaking English is in fact a native Anglophone. And it's not like there's any problem  googling **define to follow [the] suit** - which will definitely return loads of dictionary definitions - ***all*** of which will be "article-less", regardless of whether that artcle was included in the search term (which doesn't even need any "quote marks" to help google respond correctly).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica "I assume it's reasonably obvious to people living in those countries whether someone they hear speaking English is in fact a native Anglophone"
- There’s not even any need to assume that because none of them is a native Anglophone, just like neither I am. That’s why I never know whether what they say in English is an acceptable way of saying or not. 

“And it's not like there's any problem googling...” 
- Google will definitely tell me that “follow suit” is correct, but it will still leave me in suspense on whether “follow the suit” is also acceptable or not.

Comment: If *none* of the people around you are native Anglophones, don't expect to learn "correct" English from them. Even actual Anglophones use dictionaries sometimes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is *follow suit.* It's a term from certain card games, meaning to play a card of the same suit (symbol) as the previous player. By extension, to copy the action of someone else.

*Follow the suit* appears to be an error resulting from the writer's not being familiar with the original expression.